# How to calculate the trajectory of reflections from other physical objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, game-physics

Is there an easy way to calculate the expected trajectory of the bullet in the Nape? I need to build something like this path reflected no more than one or two bodis. Like billiard games. My game do not have gravity.

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is. How do you represent the velocity of the bullet, as a Cartesian vector? And are all your obstacles rectangles aligned to the X and Y axes?

Comment: Yes, the answer to both questions is yes. But objects can not only be a rectangles, but a circles. And can move. I can give more code (Nape).

Answer (score 1):

Start with a stationary rectangle.  I assume you can determine which edge the bullet will strike. If it strikes a horizontal edge (constant Y), then reverse the Y-component of the trajectory; If it strikes a vertical edge (constant X), then reverse the X-component of the velocity.

In the case of a circle, you must find the ray from the center of the circle to the point of impact, then reverse the component of the velocity parallel to that ray (do you know how to find the component of a vector parallel to a given vector?).

If the objects can move, and the speed of the bullet is much greater than the speed of the objects, then all you need is the instantaneous positions of the objects-- as far as the bullet is concerned, they are stationary.

If the objects are moving with speed comparable to the speed of the bullet, you must be able to do simple coordinate transformation, in order to shift in and out of the object's frame. For instance, if the object has velocity (2,3) and the bullet has velocity (-5, 9), then in the frame of the object the object is stationary and the bullet has velocity (-7, 6). Then you can calculate the collision in this frame (where the object is stationary), then transform back. For instance, if the object is a rectangle and the bullet hits its bottom edge, the bullet's velocity becomes (-7, -6), which we transform back into the world frame: (-5, -3).

Comment: Thank you Beta, but your explanations confused me. I'm not good at geometry, could you illustrate it with code snippets?

Comment: @Astraport, what's the first part that doesn't make sense?

Comment: I do not understand why I need velocity, because i have to draw the line trajectories of each frame. I khow the angle (in radians) of the cannon rotation and start position of the bullet. It is only necessary to determine the points of intersection the bullet with other objects, the angles of reflection and draw 2-3 line segments. Or am I wrong?

Comment: So which of those three tasks (finding points of interception, calculating angles of reflection, drawing line segments) is giving you trouble?

Comment: There are two approaches to the first task: either a) advance along the path in small steps, checking to see whether you're *inside* any of the objects, or b) solve for all intersection points and choose the nearest one. For the second task you're probably asking the wrong question, but in any case I can't explain without diagrams, and I don't have good tools for drawing them.